# Nginx deny-all fails to execute PHP code in 403.html

Tags: php, nginx, configuration

I want to deny access to some directories and files, so I use the deny_all option to return a 403.html page.  However, it does not allow me to execute any PHP code in that page.

Something to do with "internal"?  Should I use "return" or "error_page" instead?

Here's my config, any other suggestions appreciated...

```
#
#  Redirect all to www
#
server 
{
    listen 80;

    server_name site.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.site.com$request_uri;
}

#
#  Validate and process requests
#
server 
{
    listen 80;

    server_name www.site.com *.site.com;

    root /var/www/site.com;
    index index.html;
#
#  Error and Access logs
#
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.site.log notice;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.site.log;

    error_page 403 /Src/403.html;
    location = /Src/403.html 
    {
      internal;
    }

    error_page 404 /Src/404.html;
    location = /Src/404.html 
    {
      internal;
    }

    location / 
    {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.(py|sh|tgz|xml)$ 
    {
      deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.(html|php)$ 
    {
      include fastcgi.conf;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.html;
      try_files $uri.html $uri.php $uri/ =404;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `location` itself. `nginx` chooses one `location` process a request. In the case of `/Src/403.html`, the `location = /Src/404.html` block takes precedence over the `location ~ \.(html|php)$` block, which means that none of the PHP directives are included. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

If you care that the `/Src/403.html` URI remains internal, include the necessary directives into that `location` block. For example:

```
error_page 403 /Src/403.html;
location = /Src/403.html 
{
    internal;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Otherwise, you can just delete the entire location block, in which case, the `/Src/403.html` URI will be processed by the `location ~ \.(html|php)$` block.